# Trello Webhook Callbackurl VALIDATOR_URL_RETURNED_ERROR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, trello

I am in need of assistance and would appreciate any help that the community can provide, I am using Amazon Lambda and API Gateway to create a webhook for Trello. This is the URL callback that I am using. I have verified that it returns a status code of 200. However, when I try to create a webhook on my Trello board, I receive the following error

Here is my url https://1g4m5vla2i.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/trello

[image: Here is the picture]

> {
> “message”: “URL (https://1g4m5vla2i.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/trello) did not return 200 status code, got 404”,
> “error”: “VALIDATOR_URL_RETURNED_ERROR”
> }

I have used Amazon Lambda and API Gateway to set up the webhook and have confirmed that the URL callback is correct. However, I am unsure why I am still encountering this error. If anyone has experience with resolving similar issues or has any suggestions on what I can do to fix this error, please share your insights. Thank you in advance for your help.

I want can create a webhook easy or fix my url.

Comment: When I access that URL, I get: `"Hello from Lambda!AWS HUAN GET"`

Comment: yep I run a lambda function to test but it not work for trello webhook